# How to write this code in ViewModel and bind with XAML design page. Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to implement this code in ViewModel, and Design part in the XAML page.

Below you can find my code. Now it's working in Code behind C# page. But i'm trying to move this code in ViewModel page and bind with XAML design page. But I don't know how I can do this. Can you help me to do this?

Here I'm trying to bind XAML page.

```
<StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Coupons}" Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="5,5,5,0">
                                <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="20,10" Padding="20,10" BorderColor="Maroon" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding CouponName}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                            <BoxView HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Image>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding CouponLimit}" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding tgr}" />
                                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried?  where specifically are you stuck?  This is a LOT of code to ask us to convert for you, it would be helpful if you narrowed down the problem to something more manageable.  Generally, this looks like something where you could use a CollectionView or bindable StackLayout with a template for the Coupon's UI.

Comment: its also unclear why you are taking an `Coupon[]` and breaking it up into multiple `string[]` for each property.  This seems inefficient and cumbersome and doesn't provide any visible advantage over using the original array (or List or other IEnumerable)

Comment: Hii @Jason , Please look this link [link](https://github.com/AdityaRaj2025/ZZAPP/blob/main/CouponViewModel.cs)  here I'm trying to implement this code in viewmodel. but how do i handle design part. Please improve my code.

Comment: Here my XAML page [link](https://github.com/AdityaRaj2025/ZZAPP/blob/main/CouponPage.xaml) @Jason

Comment: Please read [ask] - relevant code should be included in the body of the post, not in an off-site resource.  And instead of simplifying the problem you have just added MORE code to an already very long post.  You need to narrow it down.  Do you know how to use a bindable layout?  Do you understand how to use templates?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my question. Yes I know  basics how to use a bindable layout and how to use templates. I am not too familiar of this. @Jason

Comment: I see you are using mvvmcross, maybe you can find some good example or tutorial that shows what you want to do? Otherwise, I recommend doing a simpler mvvm example first. Without mvvmcross. See [Xamarin Part 5. From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm). Once you understand what is supposed to be in ViewModel vs what stays in View, see [mvvmcross Data binding](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding).

Answer (score 2):

your VM needs to expose a `Coupons` property that is a `List` or other `IEnumerable`

```
public List<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
```

then your VM should populate `Coupons` with data from your service

then in your XAML you can use a bindable `StackLayout` or other container

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Coupons}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ... fill in the layout for a single coupon here
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

I'd strongly suggest you start as simply as possible.  Add a single `Label` to you template and get it to work with a binding.  Then add another element.  Get each one to work before you add more.  That way if you run into a problem you can easily narrow it down to the last change you make.